# "Property json does not exist on type {}" TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am VERY new to TypeScript and have a project to finish up by tomorrow. What I am trying to do is import my json file onto componentDidMount() and render that on the app. I think I am at least doing something right since when I hover over 'response', I get all the different keys and values in my JSON file. I am having trouble rendering it on my App.

Here is the code(and don't mind searchField, I am adding that later and have no errors about it atm):

```js
import * as React from "react";
import GameCardList from "../GameCardList";
import logo from "./logo.svg";

export interface IGame {
  Name: string;
  ID: number;
  Slug: string;
}

interface IAppProps {
}

interface IAppState {
  games: Array<IGame>;
  searchfield: string;
}

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<IAppProps>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: [],
      searchfield: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    import("../games.json")
      .then( response => response.json())
      //^^where the error is
      .then((users: any) => {this.setState({ games: users}); });
  }

  onSearchChange = (event: { currentTarget: { value: any; }; }) => {
    this.setState({ searchfield: event.currentTarget.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { games, searchfield } = this.state;
    const filteredGames = games.filter(game => {
      return game.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
    });
    return !games.length ?
      <h1>Hello I am Loading!!</h1> :
      (
        <div className="tc">
            <GameCardList games={filteredGames} />
        </div>
      );
  }
}

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-default-export
export default App;
```

What is interesting is that I had this EXACT same code in my other TS project with the JSON file and it is working fine. Hmm what am I doing wrong?

Also, on the topic of importing JSON in typescript file, any resources or other advice I can follow?

Comment: I don't think you need that `.json()` there. Have you tried to print `response`? From the error message, it looks like response is already the object you need.

Comment: like print(response)? I haven't tried that yet @BrunoMonteiro

Comment: `console.log(response)`. Are you new to Javascript as well? `console.log` is the command to print something in the console :)

Comment: I must have bumped my head or something, that's what I meant oops!

Comment: No problem! Did it work?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro it did! I'm confirmed for an on-site interview with the company now. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear! I posted the comment as an answer so you could accept it, if that's OK. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `.json()` there, since your response is already the object that you need.

You can test that by printing the response: `console.log(response)`